# multiple horizontal divs with same width as screen

Tags: html, css

I something like this (sort of) html:

```
<window>
    <container>
        <item 1>...</item>
        <item 2>...</item>
        <item 3>...</item>
        ...
        <item n>...</item>
    </container>
</window>
```

where n is the variable number of items.

What I'm essentially looking for is something like this in (sort of) css:

```
window { width: 100%; }
container { width: n * 100%; }
item { width: 100% of window; }
```

Or in words: Window should scale to 100% of screen width. The container should hold all items horizontally next to each other and each item should be 100% of window width.

Or in ASCII:

```
+-screen--------------+
|                     |
|                     |
|+-window------------+|
||                   ||
||+-container---------------------------------------------------+
|||                                                             |
|||+-item 1---------+ +-item 2---------+  ... +-item n---------+|
|||| = 100% of win  | |                |      |                ||
|||+----------------+ +----------------+      +----------------+|
|||                                                             |
||+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|+-------------------+|
+---------------------+
```

**Is this possibly with css only?**

Only if not what would be the prefered way of doing it with jQuery?

Tanks a lot.

(this is of course for building some horizontal slider)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you cannot calculate and fix the width of container with CSS, you could leave it at auto and do not wrap the contents. This way it will increase in width by as much child `div`s it has.

***Snippet:***

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
html, body {
    width: 100%; margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div.container {
    height: 120px;
    border 1px solid gray;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

div.r {
    height: 120px; width: 100%;
    background-color: #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="r"></div>
    <div class="r"></div>
    <div class="r"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks more simple than I expected. What I don't understand is, what makes the width:100% in r make this relative to body and not to html?

Comment: @Scheintod: The width is relative to its parent. In this case, the parent's width is not there. But, we have restricted the body to 100%, hence it is being restricted by the body width, not the parent width. If you don't restrict the body as well, then it is the entire viewport size that it will take into account.

Comment: now i get it. but this seems to be something other than what I wanted. (the container being n*100% wide). scrolling this stuff with js would then be setting a negative margin to the first element?

Comment: It should not. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/ja1t84x8/ . See console while scrolling.

Comment: Also, see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/ja1t84x8/1/ . Using jQuery to scroll the container. Check console if the margin changes.

Comment: hey, thanks for the fiddle. I think I put my question the wrong way. (And it seems to be nonesense, too) Should have been: how to I do scrolling with jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

You could have your items display as `inline-block` elements and then have the container not wrap the elements. The list items would then follow one another in-line.

Hide the overflow for your container so that the `body` isn't made wider:

```css
body{
    margin:0;
}

ul{
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

ul li{
    width:100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>List Item 1</li><!--
 --><li>List Item 2</li><!--
 --><li>List Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks. Essentially the same answer as the other one in the same time. And the same question: What I don't understand is what makes the width:100% in li relative to body and not to ul?

Comment: `ul` is 100% of `body` and `li` is 100% of `ul`, hence `li` is 100% of `body`.

Comment: s. my comment on abhitalks answer.